# Child retain percentage position in parent on scale

Tags: javascript, percentage

I have a pin (red dot) over the image that has a percentage position set.

How can I retain the pin position relative to the image when re-sizing the parent wrap container?  (resize the wrap container to see the issue)

```css
#wrap{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.pin{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  left:40%;
  top:40%;
}
img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/1200px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg"/>
  <div class="pin"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The initial top and left ratios of the `pin` w.r.t. the `wrap` are 0.4 and 0.4 respectively. Upon resizing the `wrap`, you will get the new `width` and `height` of the re-sized element. How about always maintaining a 0.4 ratio for the `pin` during resizing the `wrap` div?

Comment: Do I need javascript for that?

Comment: Yes, maybe in `on('resize')` when you get the new width and height of the resized element or if you can get this new width and height with the help of javascript inside your resize function, you can be able to maintain the same aspect ratio of the `pin`.

Comment: can you make quick sample please?

Answer (score 1):

I tried making it seamless but due to time constraints, I couldn't give my best shot. However, the `pin` is `relative` when resizing the `wrap` vertically and horizontally. Not sure how much I helped you with this.

**Note**: You can restrict the resizing up to a certain limit (*minimum width and height*) so that the `pin` does not go out of the image when a user tries to resize the `wrap` to almost "*zero(0) dimensions*".

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', positionPin);

function positionPin() {
  const img = document.querySelector('img');
  const pin = document.querySelector('.pin');
  const imgWidth = img.clientWidth;
  const imgHeight = img.clientHeight;

  const pinLeft = imgWidth * 0.4; // 40% of the image width
  const pinTop = imgHeight * 0.4; // 40% of the image height

  pin.style.left = `${pinLeft}px`;
  pin.style.top = `${pinTop}px`;
}
```

```css
#wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pin {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  left:40%;
  top:40%;

}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/1200px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg"/>
  <div class="pin"></div>
</div>
```